How to make orbit controls' center something other than the center of the canvas?
I want to rotate an object or the camera around the center of an object, however the object is not placed in the center of the canvas, a little to the left. So using OrbitControls is making the object rotate it around the center of the canvas. When I change the target of the OrbitControls to the center of the object, due to how orbit controls is defined, it is rearranging the center again to the center of the canvas.
I know OrbitControls should not be used here but I don't know what I should use then?
Even tried CameraControls but it still is rotating around the center of the canvas.

Look maybe here TrackballControls

@ŁukaszD.Mastalerz I'll definitely try it out.
However i found a way around it, to change the center I resized the canvas and in the remaining part I added another canvas. Is it a good practice?
But in the other canvas I'm loading a texture in the background using  but the texture is only loading in the first canvas not in the second one :(

You need to set the target of the Orbit Controls.
EG
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.target = mesh.position;
controls.update(); // needed to accurately set the first frame

Demo here: https://codepen.io/loficodes/pen/bGPgYJy/9b059ab08e8ad4dc3cb1c6683ca29be0

If you change the target of the orbit controls, it is coded in such way that it brings the changed target to the center of the canvas on its own, which is the main problem. Resizing the whole canvas solved my problem.
